# Using Eq (JSTL) violates MVC principles in case choosing type menu for logined user

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I faced with next problem. I use 2 kind menu( for Tutors and Students). And I decided to include menu in dependence on role logined user. All things are OK. But I use next construction:

```
<div class="left"> 
    <c:if test="${role eq 'TUTOR'}">
        <c:import url="/page/tutor/menuForTutor.jsp" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${role eq 'STUDENT'}">
        <c:import url="/page/student/menuForStudent.jsp" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

People say that using `'eq'` is a bad style. I tried to escape this situation: I created user's tag. but when I do next

```
if (Role.TUTOR.equals(role)) {
            try {
                pageContext.getOut().write("<c:import url=\"/page/tutor/menuForTutor.jsp\" charEncoding=\"UTF-8\"/>");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MenuTag.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

I cannot get that I expect because as I understand transform jsp in html occurs before creation user's tag.

Can you advice me other ways to do that I want? Thanks

P.S. And also I use localization in my jsp files for menu (fmt)

```
<fmt:bundle basename="by.bsuir.testing.resource.content" prefix="content.">
    <fmt:message key="menu" var="Menu"/>
    <fmt:message key="startPage" var="StartPage"/>
    <fmt:message key="menuitem.editInfoAboutTest" var="MenuItemEditInfoAboutTest"/>
</fmt:bundle>
<h1>${Menu}</h1>
<ul>    
    <li>
        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/page/common/login.jsp">
            ${StartPage}
        </a>
    </li>            
    <li>
        <a href="controller?command=all_Subject_Edit">
            ${MenuItemEditInfoAboutTest}
        </a>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: @DaveNewton I wrote that I tried to use custom tag. But it didn't work. Maybe I made a mistake..

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Who are those "people"? What are their arguments? Using `<c:import>` instead of `<jsp:include>` is by the way somewhat strange. You usually use `<c:import>` only for external resources or local non-JSP files.

Comment: @BalusC Teacher says me that eq on jsp in my case violates MVC principles

Comment: Go to a different school. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why 'eq' is a bad style (or '==' which is the same).

But your tag won't work, because you cannot write JSP directives to the out and expect it will work:

```
pageContext.getOut().write(
   "<c:import url=\"/page/tutor/menuForTutor.jsp\" charEncoding=\"UTF-8\"/>");
```

You can only write HTML - as it's output sent to browser, not for compiling to the web-container.

You can try to directly call `ImportTagImportTag` instead:

```
ImportTag tag = new ImportTag();
tag.setUrl("/page/tutor/menuForTutor.jsp");
tag.setCharEncoding("UTF-8");
tag.setContext(pageContext);
tag.doStartTag();
```

P.S. But I would have just used 'eq' or '==' instead.

Comment: This should be written instead of `pageContext.getOut().write(
   "<c:import url=\"/page/tutor/menuForTutor.jsp\" charEncoding=\"UTF-8\"/>");` in the tag source code.

Comment: method setContext required String

Comment: I changed `tag.setContext(pageContext);` on `tag.setPageContext(pageContext);` but it doesn't work. On jsp nothing

Comment: I would play around with setting context, pageContext, parent and other settings. You need to emulate as if this tag is in the page. Again - this is an ugly solution. I don't know who told you that 'eq' is a bad practice, but he/she doesn't seem to be right.